# How do I close an app on host "robs-MacBook-pro.local"? in terminal

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

I have received the above error message while I was opening Libre Office. Could you please let me know the steps in terminal how I (pianomusic) can close LibreOffice on the host "robs-MacBook-pro.local"? I am using terminal on a macbook pro. thanks

I actually do not know how to handle this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1.  How can I unlock my personal settings on my Mac book pro using terminal? I need to know where the file is located. 
2.  How can I close an app on host "Robs-macbook-pro.local?